# Why does ++ increment after returning the value in this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, increment, codesmith, csx

Here's the problem (with a working solution):

Create a function cycleIterator that accepts an array, and returns a function. The returned function will accept zero arguments. When first invoked, the returned function will return the first element of the array. When invoked a second time, the returned function will return the second element of the array, and so forth. After returning the last element of the array, the next invocation will return the first element of the array again, and continue on with the second after that, and so forth.

My question is in regards to line 7.

```
function cycleIterator(arr) {
    let indexCounter = 0;

  return function() {
    
    if (indexCounter >= arr.length) indexCounter = 0;
    return arr[indexCounter ++];    //WHY IS THIS [O, 1, 2] NOT [1, 2, 3]
  }
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
const threeDayWeekend = ['Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
const getDay = cycleIterator(threeDayWeekend);

console.log(getDay()); // should log: 'Fri'
console.log(getDay()); // should log: 'Sat'
console.log(getDay()); // should log: 'Sun'
console.log(getDay()); // should log: 'Fri'
```

Comment: `a++` increments after `++a` increments before

Comment: The duplicate is about C, but the basic behavior is essentially identical in JavaScript in non-exotic situations.

Comment: The ++ and -- operators are operational jargon from c, where (back in the day) ++ and -- were used to increment and decrement computer registers directly for performance purposes. In my opinion, we ought to get rid of them - it's easy to make mistakes with them as what they do is a little opaque.

Answer (score 1):

`indexCounter++` Will increment after it's read.
`++indexCounter` Will increment before it's read.